# Button comes above another button when click on each of them / Android XML

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, layer

***Hello Stack Overflow, I'm new to Android!***

I'm designing two buttons, that one of them is above another button like two layers in Photoshop.

[Button `ONE` position in Android XML editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hREq.png)

> I cannot embed photos yet!

**And here's button `ONE`:**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
        android:background="@drawable/empty_yellow_circle"
        android:text="1"
        app:backgroundTint="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

[Button `TWO` position in Android XML editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79sL.png)

**And here's button `TWO`:**
<Button

```
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/full_yellow_circle"
    android:text="2"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.558"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

**What do I want?**
I want to arrange this button as photos above, button `ONE` always stuck below button `TWO` and never comes above button `TWO`, like two **fixed layers**.

But in the test run, when I **click button `ONE`**, it **comes above button `TWO`**, and vice as **linked photo** below.

[When Click on Button ONE and vice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDohz.jpg)

> You can see in photo above that button `ONE` border comes above button `TWO` text.

so they are not fixed layers and the arrangement changes per click.
**I want a fixed arrangement.**

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the changing `transitionZ` while tapping on each button. To overcome this, put your lower button (ONE) in a standalone container (which has zero elevation) and make sure its declaration comes **before** the upper button (TWO) in your XML layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/button1_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="84dp"
        android:background="@drawable/empty_yellow_circle"
        android:text="1"
        app:backgroundTint="@null" />
</FrameLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="76dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:background="@drawable/full_yellow_circle"
    android:text="2"
    app:backgroundTint="@null"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1_container"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.558"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/button1_container"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
```

It's a bit nasty workaround but helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still have another problem: 1. Is it working for multi buttons? 2. When I try to replace button **TWO** again on the right corner of button **ONE** as before, in android studio XML editor, it's impossible to do such a thing again with mouse dragging, and when I tried hard to drag the button into exact position, the button **TWO** suddenly dropped into the **FrameLayout** and that button was part of that layout after that time.

Comment: `<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button1_container"
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"/></FrameLayout>` /// After trying to grab the button **TWO** next to button **ONE** ///

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer posted, you can put your first layout button into `<FrameLayout> ... </FrameLayout>`, then **your problem will be fixed**, but it's not the designing standards and as the poster said; **it's a little nasty**.
It doesn't work for multi buttons and you'll see problems and bugs in designing after fixing the problem by this way.

The way I fixed my problem is to add XML shapes instead of buttons, and add 0 opacity tint buttons on that shapes. So shapes are not clickable so they won't come above each others after clicking. It is nasty too but it's more responsive in designing.